# How do I unhook an lambda event handler inside the lambda method?

Tags: c#, timer, eventhandler

So I looked on SO and found how to unhook anonymous event handlers and that is no problem. But the problem I have is how to unhook the event handler inside the instance of the event handler itself.

For example I have a timer:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler handler = ((sender, args)
  =>
  {
      //aTimer.Elapsed -= handler;
      wc.CancelAsync();
  });
aTimer.Elapsed += handler;
aTimer.Interval = 100000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

With the line commented out this works fine. But then I realised there is a possible memory leak as the `ElapsedEventHandler` is never unhooked. I therefore tried to add the commented out line to my `ElapsedEventHanlder` to unhook the timer from itself.

But I cannot compile the code because of the error:

> Use of unassigned local variable "handler"

Is it possible to unhook the `Elapsed` event of my `Timer` when my timer completes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the declration and the assignment of your variable and it will work fine.

```
System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler handler = null;

handler = ((sender, args)
  =>
  {
      aTimer.Elapsed -= handler;
      wc.CancelAsync();
  });
```

The way variable capture works `handler` will not be null when the event fires, it will be the anonymous delegate.